# how to update multiple models with rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have following two models

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :office
end
```

I have a `new.html.erb` for the office model and the below code in `OfficeController`

```
  def create
    @office = Office.new(params[:deal])
    if @office.save
      redirect_to office_url, :notice => "Successfully created office."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

How can I add fields for `Location` model in `new.html.erb` of `Office`?

I want to be able to have fields for locations in the same form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use nested attributes to do this. Fortunately, Rails makes it pretty easy. Here's how to do it:

1. First, signify to Office that you're giving it Location fields as well by adding this line: 
   `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location`.
2. Now, in `new.html.erb`, add the fields that you want. Say we want to have city and state:

   ```
   <%= f.fields_for :location do |ff| %>
       <%= ff.label :city %>
       <%= ff.text_field :city %>

       <%= ff.label :state %>
       <%= ff.text_field :state %>
   <% end %>
   ```

That's it!